# how to make NestedScrollView did not have a header in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am now using NestedScrollView to show article list, this is the code I am using now:

```
return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                  context,
                ),
                sliver: SliverAppBar(


                )),
          ];
        }}
)
)
```

is it possbile to remove the header `headerSliverBuilder`? when I am removed, it shows the headerSliverBuilder can not be null. But now I do not want a header in my app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's simple. You just have to do like this:

`headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) { return []; },`